# mxnet: multiple dropout layers with shared mask

Tags: python, r, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, mxnet

I'd like to reproduce a recurrent neural network where each time layer is followed by a dropout layer, and these dropout layers share their masks. This structure was described in, among others, [A Theoretically Grounded Application of Dropout in Recurrent Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05287).

As far as I understand the code, the recurrent network models implemented in MXNet do not have any dropout layers applied between time layers; the `dropout` parameter of functions such as `lstm` ([R API](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/R-package/R/lstm.R#L4), [Python API](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/rnn/lstm.py#L19)) actually defines dropout on the input. Therefore I'd need to reimplement these functions from scratch.

However, the Dropout layer does not seem to take a variable that defines mask as a parameter.

Is it possible to make multiple dropout layers in different places of the computation graph, yet sharing their masks?

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion [here](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/ensuring-the-same-result-with-dropout-using-random-seed/392), it is not possible to specify the mask and using random seed does not have an impact on dropout's random number generator.

Comment: There is work to fix the issue with RNG, but you still cannot specify a mask.